# What Algebra steps, do I need to take in the following proof (induction proof: Recurrences)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

**Edit: Apparently my question wasn't clear enough so I will go step by step:**

I will start from the beginning:

**Claim** : Let $a_n$ be the sequence defined by $a_1=1, a_2=8,$ and $a_n= a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} $ , for $ n \ge 3$

**Proof**: Prove by strong induction that, for all $ n \in N$,

(*) $a_n= 3 \cdot2^{n-1} + 2(-1)^n$

**Base case**: When $n= 1$, the left side is $a_1=1$, and the right side is $3 \cdot2^0 + 2(-1)^1 =1 $ . So both sides are equal and (*) is true for $n=1$.

Same is the case with $n=2$. Now I move to induction step.

**Induction step**: Let $k \in N $ with $k \ge 2 $ be given and suppose (*) is true for n = 1, 2 ..... k. Then:

$a_{k+1} = a_k + 2a_{k-1}$ (by recurrence of $a_n$ )

$=3*2^{k-1} + 2(-1)^k + 2(3*2^{k-2} + 2(-1)^{k-1})  $ (by $n=k$ and $n= k-1$)

---

This is as far as I got in solving the problem. My question is how do I get to final solution: $3*2^k + 2(-1)^{k+1}$ from the last step I made.

I tried myself but I have gaps in my Algebra  knowledge, so I always got different outcome. In other words, my question is can someone solve a problem above from where I left it, step by step, pointing out why and what he used to get to the solution.

*P.S I hope this is clear enough now.If not,  please let me know  what you didn't understand like @ctst did. Also this is my first time, I ever asked online for a help to solve a math problems or used Math Stackexchange.*

Comment: Just guessing in the blue: Does $ 2(3\cdot 2^{k-2} + 2(-1)^{k-1}) = 3 \cdot 2^{k-1} + 2 \cdot 2(-1)^{k-1} = 3 \cdot 2^{k-1} + 2(-1)^{k-1} + 2(-1)^{k+1}$ help you? (Now add this with the other sum, use ($a \cdot 2^k + a \cdot 2^k= 2 \cdot a \cdot 2^k= a \cdot 2^{k+1}$)

Comment: Welcome, it is easy write formulas with our  [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Add a full description of your problem, I believe that is required a definition for $a_n$. Edit/improve your question also with the tad dedicated to mathematical induction.

Comment: @ctst Yeah, that helps a lot actually. Thanks for help and I apologize for all confusion I cause.

Comment: @steefy No problem. Now your question can be easily answered. If Scientifica's answer satisfies you, you can accept it (you should do this, to mark your question as answered and give credit). Else you can further ask him with comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is clear enaugh, indeed. I don't think you still deserve downvotes.

So, you found that $$a_{k+1}=3\times 2^{k-1}+2(-1)^k+2\times \left(3\times 2^{k-2}+2(-1)^{k-1}\right)\tag{1}$$ Your final result should be $$3\times2^k+2(-1)^{k+1}\tag{2}$$ Notice that this final expression is a sum of two terms: $3$ times a power of $2$ and $2$ times a power of $(-1)$. So why not try to regroup powers of $2$ and powers of $(-1)$ in expression $(1)$, like this:$$a_{k+1}=\left(3\times 2^{k-1}+2\times 3\times 2^{k-2}\right)+\left( 2(-1)^k+2\times 2(-1)^{k-1}\right)$$

All you need now is to simplify this expression. [You can do it!](https://media.giphy.com/media/wErJXg1tIgHXG/giphy.gif)

Comment: I can't believe how simple it was. This will definitely help me solve this and rest of more complex cases. Thanks for help !

Comment: Glad you did it. You're welcome :)